# jpa entity not update relationship actions in database

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, foreign-keys

I have component object mapped to componentMeta object, and i set cascade(javax.persistence.CascadeType) action = all, but relationship action in database still are Restrict (it's not update to cascade)

**Here are Component object:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "component")
public class Component {

    private int                     idComponent;
    private List<ComponentMeta>     componentMetas;

    public Component() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int getIdComponent() {
        return this.idComponent;
    }

    public void setIdComponent(int idComponent) {
        this.idComponent = idComponent;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "component", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<ComponentMeta> getComponentMetas() {
        return this.componentMetas;
    }

    public void setComponentMetas(List<ComponentMeta> componentMetas) {
        this.componentMetas = componentMetas;
    }
}
```

**And ComponentMeta object:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ComponentMeta")
public class ComponentMeta {

    private int idComponentMeta;
    private Component component;

    public ComponentMeta() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idComponentMeta", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getIdComponentMeta() {
        return idComponentMeta;
    }

    public void setIdComponentMeta(int idComponentMeta) {
        this.idComponentMeta = idComponentMeta;
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idComponent")
    public Component getComponent() {
        return component;
    }

    public void setComponent(Component component) {
        this.component = component;
    }
}
```

**And there are picture about relationship actions in database(not update to cascade):**
[image]

**My hibernate config in spring boot(application.properties):**

```
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

**Why the relationship actions not auto update to cascade?**

Comment: The "cascade" flags in JPA relation annotations are nothing to do with how a Foreign Key is generated as. They relate to how the JP A provider will handle persistence/update/delete and nothing more

Comment: Oh, i got it, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want hibernate to generate `ON DELETE CASCADE` on a foreign key, you need to put `@OnDelete` at `@OneToMany` side:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "component", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Relationships in JPA are always unidirectional, unless you associate the parent with the child in both directions. Cascading REMOVE operations from the parent to the child will require a relation from the parent to the child (not just the opposite).

You'll therefore need to do this:

Either, change the unidirectional @ManyToOne relationship to a bi-directional @ManyToOne, or a unidirectional @OneToMany. You can then cascade REMOVE operations so that EntityManager.remove will remove the parent and the children. You can also specify orphanRemoval as true, to delete any orphaned children when the child entity in the parent collection is set to null, i.e. remove the child when it is not present in any parent's collection.
Or, specify the foreign key constraint in the child table as ON DELETE CASCADE. You'll need to invoke EntityManager.clear() after calling EntityManager.remove(parent) as the persistence context needs to be refreshed - the child entities are not supposed to exist in the persistence context after they've been deleted in the database.

Comment: Any news ? Do you fix your problem ?